# Typescript error exporting a function with interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to learn Typescript and I have encounter a particular error as my exports of the functions are not exported as functions:

I started by making a interface for a user and then made a Type filter thru *Omit*.

```
export type role = "Client" | "Admin";

export interface User {
  id: number;
  nickname: string;
  email: string;
  verifiedEmail: boolean;
  password: string;
  role: role;
  avatar: string;
}

export type SensitiveUser = Omit<User, "email" | "password">;
```

Then I made a controller to handle information

```
import { SensitiveUser, User } from "../types";
import usersData from "./user.json";

const user: User[] = usersData as User[];

export const getUsers = (): User[] => {
  return user;
};

export const getSensitiveUser = (): SensitiveUser[] => {
  return user;
};
```

This is the JSON where i retrive the info(as if it were a fetch)

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nickname": "qwe",
    "email": "qwe@fakemail.com",
    "verifiedEmail": true,
    "password": "1234",
    "role": "client",
    "avatar": "url"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nickname": "asd",
    "email": "asd@fakemail.com",
    "verifiedEmail": false,
    "password": "1234",
    "role": "admin",
    "avatar": "url"
  },
...
]
```

And the final file its just a call of the function I exported above when I use the *http://localhost:4005*

```
import express from "express";
import * as users from "../controllers/user";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (_req, res) => {
  res.send(users.getSensitiveUser());
});

router.post("/", (_req, res) => {
  res.send("post user");
});

export default router;
```

This is the error i get if i run it:

*TypeError: users.getSensitiveUser is not a function at D:\Proyectos\listil\api\src\routes\users.ts:7:18*

If I remove the functions import and I fill the res.send() with a string, it works as intended, showing the string in the body.

This is the repo on git: https://github.com/Koppeks/Api-ts

Am i doing something wrong with the exports or imports?

Comment: I can't see the project structure, file names. Would be great to edit the post and add them or link a repo, that would be perfect. Without all that info I can make few suggestions: 1. Are there chances you have few languages, and maybe you could use letter `i` or `e` from other language. 2. Does "../controller/user" contains those operations? Couldn't you by mistake import other file and behave like it's the file you want? Try importing `import { getSensitiveUser } from '../controllers/user`. Will it provide an error?

Comment: 1- I dont understand what you mean, i only use typescript. 2- Its the only file that i can import from. I recall trying with that import style and there is no diference besides the style of the error message: *TypeError: (user_1.getSensitiveUser) is not a function at D:\Proyectos\listil\api\src\routes\users.ts:7:18*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here that transpiler (`ts-node-dev` in your case) fetches first file it sees (I'm not sure why it behaves like that, It should be investigated more, but it is as it is). And this file - is user.json file. You can see same error here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47870 I'd recommend to rename file (bd_users.json or whatever) OR place in some separate folder, where you'll store json files that will serve as db for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. I thought that the order of reading file in Typescript was: * ts, tsx, js, jsx, json.* But looks like its not.